# Is it possible to do a swap on return in c++, instead of return by value?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, swap

Suppose I'm coding a string class in C++ (I know I can use the library). The string length is variable and the storage space is dynamically allocated in the constructor and freed in the destructor. When the `main` function calls `c=a+b` (`a,b,c` are strings), the `operator+` member function creates a temporary object that stores the concatenated string `a+b`, returns it to the `main` function, and then the `operator=` member function is called to free the string originally stored in `c` and copy data from the temporary string `a+b` to `c`, and finally the temporary `a+b` is destructed.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this happen: instead of having the `operator=` copy data from `a+b` to `c`, I want it to swap the data pointers of `a+b` and `c`, so that when `a+b` is destructed, it destructs the original data in `c` (which is what we want), while `c` now takes the result of `a+b` without needing to copy.

I know coding a 2-parameter member function `setToStrcat` and calling `c.setToStrcat(a,b)` can do this. For example, the function can be coded as:

```
    void String::setToStrcat(const String& a,const String& b){
      String tmp(a.len+b.len); int i,j;
      for(i=0;i<a.len;i++) tmp[i]=a[i];
      for(j=0;j<b.len;i++,j++) tmp[i]=b[j];
      tmp[i]='\0'; this->swap(tmp);
    }

    void String::swap(String& a){
      int n=len; len=a.len; a.len=n;
      char *s=str; str=a.str; a.str=s;
    }
```

I omitted the definitions of my constructor (which allocates `len+1` char-type spaces) and `operator[]` (which returns a reference of the `i`th character). The `swap` function swaps the data pointers and length variables between `*this` and `tmp`, so that when `tmp` is destructed after the swap, it is actually the data originally stored in `*this` (the `String c` in the `main` function) that is destructed. What `*this` now has in its possession (`c.str`) is the concatenated string `a+b`.

I would like to know if there is a way to optimize the performance of `c=a+b` to the same level. I tried `c.swap(a+b)` and changed the return type of `a+b` to `String&`, but I receive warning (reference to a local variable) and GDB shows that the temporary gets destructed before the swap happens, while I want the other way.

I think my question is general. In C++ programming, we often need a temporary object to store the result of a function, but when we assign it to another object in the main function, can we not copy the data but use a (much faster) swap of pointers instead? What is a neat way of making this happen?

Comment: There is a neat way :) Search for move semantics, more specifically: move constructors and move assignment operator.

Comment: Haven't heard of move semantics yet? [Read up.](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+move+semantics)

Comment: What you are talking about looks like [copy elision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization). In C++ it will become guaranteed since C++17.

Comment: Helpful links: [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).

Comment: In my compiler, if I do `String c=a+b;` the `operator=` is not called (a byte-by-byte copy of the pointer value and length variable was done instead, I guess). This is copy elision. But if I do `String c; c=a+b;`, the `operator=` is called. This is correct, because otherwise the original data in c (the empty string) is not freed. All I want is a swap-based copy (swapping data pointers of `a+b` and `c`), rather than no copy (which would be incorrect in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, you can do this by writing a move constructor. Rvalue references were added to the language to solve this exact problem.

```
class String {
  ...
  String(String&& s) : str(nullptr) {
    this->swap(s);
  }
  String& operator=(String&& s) {
    this->swap(s);
  }
  ...
  String operator+(String const& other) {
    // (your implementation of concatenation here)
  }
  ...
}
```

Then code like this will not trigger an extra copy constructor or a memory allocation, it will just move the allocated memory from the temporary (the thing returned from operator+) to the new object `c`.

```
String c = a + b;
```

Comment: `String c = a + b;` may perform copy elision anyway

Comment: I see. The temporary string `a+b` is an rvalue. To refer to it, I should use an rvalue reference. The `operator=` of the `String` class can be 2-fold overloaded, one taking const lvalue references and doing deep copy, and the other taking rvalue references and doing swap of pointers. When the compiler cannot decide which one to call, use the `std::move` semantics to explicitly convert to rvalues. One more question to make sure: is the `a+b` still destructed after `c=a+b`?

Comment: Yes, it's destructed, but it contains `nullptr`, so it does not deallocate anything.

Comment: I tried it in c++11. It worked just as I wanted. Thank you! One can either swap `a+b` with `c` and let the destructor of `a+b` deallocate the old data of `c`, or deallocate `c` in the overloaded `operator=` that takes rvalue references, copy the pointer of `a+b` to `c`, and set the pointer of `a+b` to `nullptr` (or 0) to tell the destructor not to do anything. In C++ programming, the less "magical" way is always better.